# Unable to npm install web3 on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, ethereum

I followed every thing on this page:

https://medium.com/@PrateeshNanada/steps-to-install-testrpc-in-windows-10-96989a6cd594

Except step number 5 where my Node.js version is 8.10.0 instead of 8.10.2 which iI dont think is a big difference.

I have installed VS 2017 Community Edition, Windows 10 SDK, OpenSSL, npm-gyp.

I have run the command npm install --global --production windows-build-tools to install all the latest build tools and still get this error. Help is needed.

```
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7:   WARNING  tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt\build\..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: build/binding.sln
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'
npm WARN System32 No description
npm WARN System32 No repository field.
npm WARN System32 No README data
npm WARN System32 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-11T17_47_58_702Z-debug.log
```

It appears to me that node-gyp rebuild is failing on my machine. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the command 
`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
in powershell?

I had the same issue and running the command in powershell worked.